# run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':method 'add' of object 'listrows' failed'

Tags: vba

When I execute the ADD button I get an error message: run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':method 'add' of object 'listrows' failed However, if I remove the "ListBox2" FORM it works fine. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the VBA code:

```
Private Sub AddExpenses_Click() 
    Dim ws As Worksheet 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 
    If StaffName = "" Then 
        MsgBox "Vendor NAME cannot be empty.." 
        StaffName.SetFocus 
        Exit Sub 
    ElseIf ClientName = "" Then 
        MsgBox "GL ACCOUNT cannot be empty.." 
        ClientName.SetFocus 
        Exit Sub 
    ElseIf FoodDrink = "" Then 
        MsgBox "Total Invoice Amount cannot be empty.." 
        FoodDrink.SetFocus 
        Exit Sub
    End If 

     'If CheckForErrors > 0 Then Exit Sub
    Set ws = Sheets("Expense Report") 
    ws.Activate 
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Expenses").ListRows.Add 
    ModifyTableRow ExpensesTable.ListRows(ExpensesTable.ListRows.Count).Range 
    ChangeRecord_SpinDown 
    UpdatePositionCaption 
    Call calcul 
    ListBox2 = "expenses" 
    Worksheets("expense report").Activate 
    ThisWorkbook.Save 
End Sub 

Sub ModifyTableRow(TableRow As Range) 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 

    Worksheets("expense report").Select 
    Selection.Activate 
    Misc = "" 
    PriorHST = "" 
    TableRow.Select 
    Selection.Activate 
    With TableRow 
        MsgBox "The last ROW is: " & TableRow.Address 
        .Cells(1, 1) = Calendar1.Value 
        .Cells(1, 3) = StaffName.Value 
        .Cells(1, 5) = ClientName.Value 
        .Cells(1, 6) = Description.Value 
         '.Cells(1, 7) = ReceiptsYes.Value
         '.Cells(1, 7) = ReceiptsNo.Value
        .Cells(1, 8) = Airfare.Value 
        .Cells(1, 9) = Accommodation.Value 
        .Cells(1, 10) = GroundTransport.Value 
        .Cells(1, 11) = FoodDrink.Value 

        If ReceiptsYes.Value = True Then 
            .Cells(1, 7) = "Yes" 
        Else 
            .Cells(1, 7) = "No" 
        End If 

        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Misc = .Cells(1, 12) 
        Misc = Format(Misc, "$#,##.00") 

        PriorHST = .Cells(1, 13) 
        PriorHST = Format(PriorHST, "$#,##.00") 
    End With 

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 
End Sub
```

Comment: My guess is that there is no ListObject named "Expenses". Maybe it's "expenses" or something else? You can try `ListObjects(1)` etc. to reference element of collection by index, rather than by name, at least for testing.

Comment: What line is throwing the error?

Comment: I am unable to replicate the error...but when the error occurred it did not give the option to debug; it just gave me the error message.

However, I will keep you posted if it does reoccur...anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: I was able to replicate the error however, as I had mentioned earlier it just gives me the error message and when I click on the debug button it displays a message "Microsoft Excel has stopped working" ...